# explain on view shows derived while explain on select shows simple select type

Tags: mysql, view, explain

I have a view `v` which involves a couple of sub-selects in its `SELECT` clause plus a couple of joins by `id` or indexed column.

The view query is like:

```
SELECT col1, col2, (SELECT ... FROM subt) AS col3 FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON [..]
```

The fact is that if I query that view by `col1`, which is pk of `t1`:

```
SELECT * FROM v WHERE col1='some value'
```

the `EXPLAIN` shows a bunch of `DERIVED` tables, but if I run the same query on the view `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT col1, col2, (SELECT ... FROM subt) AS col3 FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON [..] WHERE col1='some value'
```

those same tables show up as `SIMPLE`.

How's that? I need to fix that view because it is not using some indices (although all joins are by pk or indexed columns), but I'm stuck on those `DERIVED` rows and I can't go further on my analysis.

### UPDATE

For comparison, I've run a couple more explains on a view that doens't show  these different execution plans for the same `WHERE` clause.

Given the view `v1` create with `CREATE VIEW v1 AS v_select_stmt`, the plan for the query:

```
SELECT * FROM v_crm_v1 v WHERE v.id='some value'
```

gives all plan steps with `select_type=simple`.

The plan for:

```
[v_select_stmt] AND id='some value'
```

yields all the steps with `select_type=simple` too (and they're identical to the previuos query plan).

Finally, in the plan for:

```
SELECT * FROM ( [select_stmt] ) v WHERE id='some value'
```

the steps have all `select_type=derived`.

Comment: `SELECT ... FROM ( SELECT FROM [subselect as view] ) WHERE ...` is not equivalent to `SELECT FROM [subselect as view] WHERE ...` in execution. So plans differs.

Comment: @Akina I see your point and (not aiming at contradicting you :-)) I've done some more tests. Please see my update.

Comment: Do you have any case where the `VIEW` version runs _faster_?  My impression is that a `VIEW` is syntactic sugar, _not_ a performance booster.  And the differences you are finding may highlight the failure to optimize a view as well.

Comment: @RickJames Of course not, a view is not a performance optimization (generally at least, maybe materialized views could be); the point here is that a view **should not** be slower than a regular query aiming at giving the same results - so yes it is syntactic sugar and it also makes the above software layer easier to write. Thus, my expectation is to write a view with the same performance of a query and I'm looking for pointers at how to investigare where the problem arises in my case.

Comment: @watery - When `VIEWs` were added, it seemed to be done with an attitude of "OK, now MySQL has Views".  Later came the concept of Merge versus Template Algorithms.  As recently as 5.7.6, I see a changelog entry saying "consistent optimization to merge vs materialize in derived table vs VIEW".  5.7.7 seemed to first allow a derived table in a View.